# Joda DateTime Offset Issues

Tags: jodatime

I'm trying to get the correct offset so I can use it to perform some calculations but am having problems.  I am always getting zero for the offset when I know at this point it should be 5.  If anyone could help pinpoint the issue it would help greatly.

```
DateTimeZone dateTz = DateTimeZone.forID('America/Chicago')
DateTime now = new DateTime(dateTz)
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("UTC");
long offsetInMilliseconds = tz.getOffset(now.getMillis())
```

Variable offsetInMilliseconds will always be 0 when it should be the correct offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it looks like I need to be using getOffsetFromLocal rather than getOffset, mystery solved.